# How to generate random 3D-graph and displays its adjacncency matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, adjacency-matrix

I have generated 3D points in matlab. I need it to be form random graph and display its connectivity such that connected link is 1 and 0 otherwise.. suggestions..

```
n=10;
PlotSizex=100;
PlotSizey=100;
PlotSizez=-100;
x=PlotSizex*rand(1,n)
y=PlotSizey*rand(1,n)
z=PlotSizez*rand(1,n)
plot3(x(:),y(:),z(:),'O-')
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you generate is not really a graph, it's just a set of randomly generated 3D points, graphically represented connected with a line (the `'O-'` option in the `plot3` function). But, being that they are "sequentially" connected, their [Adjacency Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) will just be a `n*n` matrix with the upper and lower diagonals filled with ones, and the rest zeros (taking the method from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763909/creating-a-tridiagonal-matrix-in-matlab)):

```
A = full(gallery('tridiag', n, 1, 0, 1))

% A =

% 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
% 1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
% 0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
% 0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
% 0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
% 0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
% 0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
% 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
% 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
% 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: I am sorry but your question is not very clear, and I am not sure if "[connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory))" is really what you are looking for. By the way, have you tried looking at this page? [Graph with undirected edges](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph-object.html).

Comment: Exactly graph with undirected edges but should displayed in 3D manner.